# Can anything in the future tense be a proposition?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, philosophy

How I learned propositions is that: if we don't know, then it is not a proposition.

For example, x = 1 is not a proposition. But, let's define boolean x = (tomorrow whether or not the event occurs). So, 1 = event occurs and 0 = event does not occur.

Thus, my English sentence translates into (x = 1) := (tomorrow = event occurrence)

I'm in some disagreement as to whether or not future-tenses are propositions. Please confirm this reasoning or not.

Comment: it depends on the type of formal logic you're using. Specifically, temporal logic - a type of modal logic - allows future tenses. This problem is known as the problem of future contigents, by the way.

Comment: I'd say this is more of a philosophical question than a logical one. Propositions have truth values. There is real philosophical disagreement about whether future contingent claims like "It will rain tomorrow" bear truth values.

Comment: @aduh I'd disagree as my main point is that variables are assigned to outcomes, thus if x + 1 = 2 cannot be a proposition, then neither can anything that can be represented by a variable be a proposition. This isn't a philosophy question

Comment: I think you need to be clearer about what you're asking then. The reason that $x+1=2$ is not a proposition/sentence is that it contains a free variable, that's all. The criterion, "if we don't know, then it's not a proposition" is not nearly precise enough for doing logic.

Comment: See [Future Contingents](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/future-contingents/) for the philosophical discussion.

Answer (score 2):

> "How I learned propositions is that: if we don't know, then it is not
>   a proposition."

There are plenty of propositions, including mathematical propositions, of which we do not whether they are true or not. For example, take $N$ to be your favourite very large prime, and consider the proposition "$2^N - 1$ is prime" (Unless you are an ultra-finitist!), that's a determinate proposition, being brute-force decidable in principle, but we don't know whether it is true.

> " x = 1 is not a proposition"

Yes, ripped out of any context, it isn't a complete proposition: but that isn't an issue about knowledge, it is an issue about incompleteness.

> "I'm in some disagreement as to whether or not future-tenses are propositions."

Tenses aren't the sort of thing that can be propositions, though being future tensed can be a *property* of some propositions. (We might reasonably hold, though, that purely mathematical propositions are tenseless.)

Perhaps you are confusing the issue about whether there can be future tensed propositions (like "there will be a sea-battle tomorrow"), with the quite different issue of whether a future tensed proposition can have a determinate truth-value now, before the time it is about (a debate that goes as far back as Aristotle, whose example the sea-battle proposition is).